# remove cell from TableViewController

Tags: swift, tableview

I want delete cell from tableViewController, But the problem is deleting the next cell 
Example : 
array : [1,2,3,4,5]
when i'm delete 2 from table, automatically the code deleting 3 from DataBase

here is my code :

```
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == .Delete {
        array_prodacts.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row) 
        tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
        let currentCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! TableViewCell2 }}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here `array_prodacts.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)` because the `tableview` is zero based index so `indexPath` of the element 1 in your array is 0, 2 is 1, 3 is 2, 4 is 3 and 5 is 4. So deleting the index 2 reflects the deleting of the value 3 (has index 2) in your array

Comment: Yes you are right , but how can i solve it ?
i already now that but i'm looking for the correct code

Comment: Probably this will solve your issue `array_prodacts.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row - 1)`